# Azure Mobile Services data into UITableView IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, azure

I have an block to run to get a query set of data from a Azure Database : 
[query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {

How can i get the *items and put it in a tableview ? As I cannot see this variable out of the block. I have tried to assign an external __ array in the block , but no use.

Has anyone tried to do this ?

thanks

Jason

Comment: you can assign items array to some external array or the array which you using in your tableView delegate methods to returnNoOfRows... any problem in that approach??

Comment: [query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
        
    [AlertArray addObject:items]; I then put a break point in it and AlertItems has got the stuff from *items, but when i go out of the block and do NSLog(@"Number of people in the database: %li", [AlertAray count]); it comes back as 0.. Strange!

Comment: try with [alertArray addObject:[item copy]]...

Answer (score 0):

i think you need some thing like this

```
[RSSParser parseRSSFeedForRequest:request success:^(NSArray *feedItems) {

    self.linkArray=feedItems;//
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //3
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });

} 
failure:^(NSError *error) { }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see how this should work is to download the Quickstart application from the Windows Azure Portal after you create a Mobile Service.  The quickstart is a Todo application that pulls down todo items you have added and displays them in a ListView.  When you call your Mobile Service's read method, you specify a callback as seen here:

```
[query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *results, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
{
    [self logErrorIfNotNil:error];

    items = [results mutableCopy];

    // Let the caller know that we finished
    completion();
}];
```

In this method, a QSCompletionBlock called completion is called from the readWithCompletion method when it's received a response from your Mobile Service.  In the Quickstart, that completion looks like this:

```
[self.todoService refreshDataOnSuccess:^
{
    if (self.useRefreshControl == YES) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

This then triggers the tableview to reload data.  There are other methods that are part of the TableViewController class that are necessary to bind the data to the table view though so I'd highly recommend walking through the Quickstart code.

Comment: So, creating an external array will not work then ? All I know is that I am struggling with it , it cannot be seen etc. Also I have assigned a dictionary so I can split the array into tables/rows from the sql server. How the todolist demo looks - it looks very scary indeed for someone who is just doing there first app!

Comment: There are different ways of doing it but I would suggest keeping an NSArray property in one of your classes which you can use to store the data you retrieve back.  The Mobile Services SDK is pretty simple but if this is your first experience with iOS, the actual iOS code might seem very confusing.  I would highly recommend digging through some tutorials on iOS development before focusing on Mobile Services.  I did a series of tutorials which can help: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS

Comment: thans Chris,I will battle on somehow. I have already been through your series. I know quite a lot from it and quite a lot in iOS dev. I am just banging my head with this bit - and its only quite simple!